# Unable to refer css file in Drupal 6 theme for formatting a table

Tags: php, css, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have been trying to work with applying css to a Drupal page of mine but the changes i do do not reflect.
The following is the screenshot of my page (a dashboard page) http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1145-262.html . My aim is to format the table listing to show 10 rows at 
a time so that the table is scrollable to view all the rows (rather than how its spread across the entire page now).
The below given is the code.

```
function freeway_dashboard(){
 drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module') .'/css/dashboard_file.css');
 //echo(drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module') .'/css/dashboard_file.css');
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module') .'/js/dashboardscript.js');

  $listOfProjectsIds = array();
  $listOfProjectsDesc = array();
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $form = array();
  $arrayStatus = array(1 =>'Draft',2=>'NotSpecified',3=>'Quote',4=>'Forecasted',5=>'InEvaluation',6=>'Cancelled',7=>'Booked',8=>'InProduction',9=>'Completed',10=>'Closed');


            $LoginClient = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/FreewayAuth.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1)); 
            $ServicesLink = new SoapClient("https://freeway.demo.lionbridge.com/vojo/Service.asmx?wsdl", array("trace"=>1));


              try{

              $arrResponse = $LoginClient->Logon(array ('Username'=>'user','Password'=>'Password'));
              $ticket = ($arrResponse->LogonResult);
              $getSrcLang = $ServicesLink->GetSourceLanguages(array('Ticket'=>$ticket));
              $getDraftProjectIds = $ServicesLink->GetProjectSummariesList(array('Ticket'=>$ticket,'NumberOfProjects'=>100,'SortOrder'=>MostRecent,'ProjectStatusCode'=>'Draft'));

                            foreach ($getDraftProjectIds->GetProjectSummariesListResult->ProjectSummaries->ProjectSummary as $i=>$getDraftProjectIds->GetProjectSummariesListResult->ProjectSummaries->ProjectSummary) 
                            {

                             $listOfProjectsIds[$i] = $getDraftProjectIds->GetProjectSummariesListResult->ProjectSummaries->ProjectSummary->ID;                     
                             $listOfProjectsDesc[$i] = $getDraftProjectIds->GetProjectSummariesListResult->ProjectSummaries->ProjectSummary->Description;                       
                            } 

              }
                  catch (SoapFault $exception){
                  return $exception;
              }


        $form['status_list']=array(
                '#type'=>'select',
                '#title' => t('Freeway Project Statuses'),
                '#options' => $arrayStatus,
                '#default_value' => ('Draft'),
                '#attributes'=> array('onselect' => "populateStatusTables();"),
                '#weight'=>3,
            );

    $header = array('Project ID', 'Project Description'); 
    $rows = array(); 

    for($m=0;$m <count($listOfProjectsIds);$m+=1){

    $rows[$m] = array($listOfProjectsIds[$m], $listOfProjectsDesc[$m]) ;

    }


    $form['table'] = array( 
     '#value' => theme('table', $header, $rows, array( 'class' => 'table_class','id'=>'dashboard_Table')), 
     //'#value' => '<div class="table_class_wrapper">'. theme('table', $header, $rows, array('class' => 'table_class','id'=>'dashboard_Table')) .'</div>',
    '#weight' => 4, 
    );


    return $form;

}
```

I have given the css class mention to the code at $form['table'] element in its value.
 I have tried to use the css inclusion using:

```
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module') .'/css/dashboard_file.css');
```

The css file is placed at 'C:\xampp\htdocs\drupalTheme\sites\all\modules\freeway_module\css'.
 The following is the code in the css file.

```
    .table_class { 
height: 200px; 
overflow: auto; 
}
```

But still i guess the code is not able to access the css file. Am i including the file correct? Looking forward for your advice.

Thanks
Angela.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path to the CSS rather than a relative path. Just figure out exactly where the CSS file is on the server and point to it... Then, you can backtrack and figure out what the relative path should be.

Comment: Hi Fred thanks for your sugestion, i put the entire path and yet it wont reflect any change. Are the contents inside my .css file correct to hav a table with scrollbar and say for eg 10 rows per view?....i tried putting my css inside modules\node\ folder since in the view source i am able to see the mention of my css. Here are the code bits i added...drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module') .'modules/node/dashboard_file.css'); and here is the view source http://pastebin.com/rvpbsRbP the name of my css is dashboard_file.css.... looking forward for your suggestion

Comment: Try adding background-color:red to a td tag to see if your site is picking up a stylesheet... The property you need for a scrollbar is overflow:scroll. However, you can't actually add it to a table. You have to wrap your table in a div and add the scrollbar to the div. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/J5kXh/

Comment: But did you look in the `<head>` part of the page to see if there is a link to the css file? Because if there isn't one then there's an issue with the path. If there's a link to `dashboard_file.css` then you have a css problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable any CSS/JS caching.
2. (Download and) Enable the devel module.
3. Change your `drupal_add_css()` call to something like the following:

> ```
> $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'freeway_module');
> dpm($path . '/css/dashboard_file.css');
> drupal_add_css($path . '/css/dashboard_file.css');
> ```

1. Empty the Drupal cache just to be sure.
2. Check the HTML source or alternatively, use something like Firebug to see if your CSS is being included. Firebug should also tell you why your CSS is not working in case it is being included correctly.

Good luck!